opkg install openssh-sftp-server is not working in openwrt 22.03.0-rc6
Using OpenWrt 22.03.0-rc6 r19590-042d558536 on a:
   Package architecture Target  Subtarget   Brand     Model         Version

    mipsel_24kc         ramips    mt76x8    GL.iNet GL-MT300N       v2

I can not install openssh-sftp-server as it doesnt is present on the repository https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/22.03.0-rc6/packages/mipsel_24kc/packages/
root@myopenwrtdevice:~# opkg install openssh-sftp-server
Unknown package 'openssh-sftp-server'.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package openssh-sftp-server.

root@orchestraGW:~# opkg find openssh-sftp-server
root@orchestraGW:~#


I compiled locally using a fork of the openwrt repositories so you can follow the instructions on the readme file or dowload the package from the repository:
https://github.com/jonathantito/openwrt/blob/main/bin/packages/mipsel_24kc/packages/openssh-sftp-server_9.7p1-r2_mipsel_24kc.ipk
or if you dont trust my file, you can use (at your own risk) the file on:
https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/23.05.3/packages/mipsel_24kc/packages/openssh-sftp-server_9.7p1-1_mipsel_24kc.ipk
